# Rails 3 Internationalization (I8n) locale set from domain name problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, nginx, setlocale

I created one rails 3 website which can be reached at whereisdaniel.com and whereisdaniel.ru The website at .com should serve up the English version and the site at .ru should serve up the Russian version.

**Locally, everything works.** However, at my deployed website everything works at first, but after going to the .ru site, trying to switch to the .com version results in a Russian translation. The only thing I can figure is that there is some sort of problem with my nginx / passenger configuration.

My configuration file looks like this:

```
nginx.conf

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name whereisdaniel.com whereisdaniel.ru;
  root /home/dan/whereisdaniel/public/;
  passenger_enabled on;
}
```

The rest of my code I cut and pasted directly from the Rails Guides here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-domain-name

**One more smaller / additional problem:**
The only thing I didn't implement from the Rails Guides was this part of the guide because I didn't understand how:

```
link_to("Deutsch", "#{APP_CONFIG[:deutsch_website_url]}#{request.env['REQUEST_URI']}")
```

Instead of this I just have basic html links to the different site urls. Actually, I'd like to understand how to how/where to create that APP_CONFIG constant if anyone knows.

Answer (score 1):

A comment over at this link solved my question:
[Rails: How should Phusion Passenger and I18n.locale behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559382/rails-how-should-phusion-passenger-and-i18n-locale-behave)

In Rails 3.0.4 there appears to be a bug. Here is a workaround:

In the application controller, the set_locale before filter should look as follows:

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = I18n.default_locale
  I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_tld
end
```

The only thing I'm wondering about now is that APP_CONFIG variable.